# What is an Instance in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to understand the basic structures associated with SQL.  I have run across the word "Instance". Looking the term up I end with:

A set of memory structures that manage database files.

What is an instance in PL/SQL?  In laymen's terms is this a separate interaction with the PL/SQL installation?

For instance (sorry for the pun) when I have an instance open I am interacting with the database by writing queries and assigning data.  I could have several instances open with which I manage data files.

Comment: I couldn't explain better than this: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1631683800346891854

Comment: And then there is an instance of a PL/SQL type... (because PL/SQL is an object-oriented programming language)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -  In the context of the question it appears that 'instance' refers to the DB instance. However, assumptions are dangerous so 'good call'.

Comment: @BriteSponge: but the question's title is "an instance in PL/SQL" - but that might just be a confusion caused by not knowing the details

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I'll edit my answer to cover the possibility.

Comment: What context did you see the word "instance" used in? e.g. was it about "connecting to an instance", or "a new instance of a type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, an Instance is the Environment you're working on. For example, i'm currently working on our Development Environment, i could interchangeably say, I'm working on our Development Instance. And as stated in the comments, Instance is not a PL/SQL or SQL concept, rather, its a Database concept.

SQL and PL/SQL are the languages that you can run in your Instance.

Comment: An "instance" can also be a "PL/SQL concept": [from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7096)  "*A constructor method is a function that returns a new instance of the user-defined type*"

Answer (score 0):

An instance in Oracle terms is the collection of memory structures and Oracle processes that are required for the DBMS to be considered operational.

The database is the set of physical files that make the database persistent.

There is no separate 'database instance' for PL/SQL or SQL. Those are two ways that you can access the data in the datafiles through the instance. Other ways might be SQL*Load, Datapump, etc.

Edit:
There is however the concept in PL/SQL of an instance of a user-defined type. You may define an object type in the database and when you use that type in your code you will create an instance of it.

Comment: Yes there is something like a "PL/SQL instance": you can create an object type in PL/SQL and then create an instance of that type.